# Pass and use argument as is

Tags: macros, arguments

I'm trying to pass data that contains (and needs to keep) newlines and all kinds of special chars (like `ä`, `$`, `"`, `\`, ...) to a command. The idea is to then write the data to a file, run it through an external parser which creates a picture and to finally include the picture. This would allow all kinds of languages (that can be parsed to a image or PDF or so) to be written directly in a `LaTeX` file.

I've got it to work except for the special characters which got me wondering:

- how can I pass and use data as is (unless of course it contains something like `\end`)? What's the best/easiest/most fool-proof/most **widespread** way to approach this?

Comment: `\write\zzz{\detokenize{......}}` perhaps.

Comment: The package [filecontents](https://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) might be of interest. The `+V`-argument-type of [xparse](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) might be of interest.  How to handle indentation in the .tex-file when the argument of `\command` spans several lines?  Shall indentation at the beginnings of lines within the argument also yield indentation in the external file?  By the way: When TeX reads input, it always does some pre-processing which cannot be prevented: All space-characters at the right get removed and a character according to `\enlinechar` gets appended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these inputs. If the \detokenize-method works that would by very simple.
filecontents sounds promising for the intended purpose. I'll give those two a try tomorrow.

Comment: `\detokenize` alone will double hashes and won't obey line-breaks in the source. These things need to be taken into account at the time of reading the .tex-file and tokenizing. Iirc `filecontents` will turn horizontal tabs into spaces. Another issue you can't change is that `\write` will always append a line-break/will always append the character-combination that denotes a line-break on your platform to the line it writes. Therefore when viewing the file created by (La)TeX in an editor, there will always be a last line which is empty.

Comment: @UlrichDiez A text file whose last line isn't empty is anomalous, you know. :-)

Comment: @frougon It would indeed be anomalous. Because each line of text should end with the characters which with the computer-platform in question denote the end of a line (CR/LF/CR+LF/whatsoever). It is about "copying" a macro-argument to external file. I intended to point out: The end of the macro-argument will be at a closing brace `}` and thus without things that denote the end of a line while "copying" to file will in the file yield these things that denote the end of a line.

Comment: @UlrichDiez To be clear: what I meant is that some tools that process text files ignore the contents of a file that follows the last end-of-line character sequence. IIRC, some versions of `cat` did that, for instance. As you say, this can be interpreted as: a legal line is ended by the end-of-line character sequence, thus what follows the last end-of-line character sequence, which is generally displayed as the last “line,” is not valid.

Comment: @frougon Yes, that's it. One consequence is: You cannot use consecutive `\write`-directives for appending things to the same line of the text-file. In this aspect (La)TeX's `\write` differs from the write-procedures of programming-languages like `C++` or `Pascal`. E.g., in Pascal the `write`-procedure will append to the current line. (La)TeX's `\write` is more like Pascal's `writeln`-procedure which does also end the line.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you wish a macro/a command which can produce within an external text file an exact copy of that portion of the .tex-input-file, which in the .tex-input-file denotes that macro's argument.

---

If you were not asking for a command/if an environment would be suficient, I'd suggest the `filecontents*`-environment from the LaTeX 2ε-kernel.

With LaTeX-releases prior to Fall 2019 the `filecontents*`-environment could only be used in the document's preamble and did not overwrite existing files.

But there is the package [filecontents](https://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) which removes these restrictions by providing the same environment(s) in a way where usage of the environments is not restricted to the preamble and where existing files will be overwritten.

So you can use the `filecontents*`-environment for creating temporary files which can be overwritten right after reading them back via `\input`/`\include`/`\read`/whatsoever or after having them post-processed by other programs whereby post-processing can probably be initiated from within the (La)TeX-run by means of TeX's `\write18`-functionality.

[Some explanation of the `\write18`-feature](https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/what-does-write18-mean/) can be found on https://www.texdev.net, written and maintained by [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright).

When it comes to using more recent LuaTeX-based engines where the `\write18`-feature is not available by default as these engines provide means for implementing it, the [shellesc](https://ctan.org/pkg/shellesc)-package might be of interest.

If you wish to create files with images in .eps-format and to use the .eps-files in `\includegraphics` of the [graphicx](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)-package when running pdflatex/xelatex for creating a .pdf-file, the package [epstopdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) may be of interest. That package converts .eps-files to .pdf-files "on the fly" during the pdflatex-run. With more recent TeXLive-distributions pdflatex will invoke `epstopdf` under the hood when `\includegraphics` is used for including an .eps-image. With other TeX-distributions [epstopdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) may need to be loaded explicitly **after** [graphicx](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) .

Here is an example where the `filecontents*`-environment is used for creating an .eps-file (whose name will be the file name of the .tex-file + the phrase `Picture`, with extension `.eps`) and a text file containing a latex picture environment (whose name will be the file name of the .tex-file + the phrase `Picture`, with extension `.lpe`—lpe being my abbreviation for **L**aTeX-**P**icture-**E**nvironment).

I currently use pdflatex from TeXLive 2019 where .eps-to-.pdf-conversion is done under the hood on the fly automatically, so on my system the example compiles without problems.

If you save the example as `test.tex`, then (besides the usual auxiliary-files and .log-file) the files `testPicture.eps` and `testPicture.lpe` will be created during compilation with pdflatex. `testPicture.eps` is an .eps-image which can be viewed, e.g., with GSview or gv. `testPicture.lpe` is a text-file containing a `picture`-environment. Conversion of the .eps-file to .pdf will deliver a file with a .pdf-image whose name is `testPicture-eps-converted-to.pdf`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{shellesc} % <- implements the \write18-interface (which is
                       %     needed by epstopdf) for more recent LuaTeX-
                       %     based engines
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}


% An .eps graphic by means of filecontents:
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname Picture.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 50 50
%%Title: (EXAMPLE.EPS)
%%CreationDate: 18/02/2020 18:09:07 +0200
%%EndComments
newpath 25 25 24 0 360 arc stroke
newpath 25 25 18 225 315 arc stroke
newpath 18 33 2 0 360 arc fill stroke
newpath 32 33 2 0 360 arc fill stroke
showpage
%%EOF
\end{filecontents*}


% A LaTeX 2e picture-environment by means of filecontents:
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname Picture.lpe}
\begingroup
\unitlength=1pt\relax
\thicklines
\begin{picture}(51,51)(0,0)
\put(26,26){\circle{40}}
\put(19,34){\circle*{4}}
\put(33,34){\circle*{4}}
\put(26,22){\oval(24,24)[b]}
\end{picture}
\endgroup
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\section{A picture by LaTeX's picture-environment}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\input{\jobname Picture.lpe}
\caption{A picture by LaTeX's picture-environment}
\end{figure}

\section{An .eps-graphic (probably auto-converted to .pdf via the pstopdf-package)}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{\jobname Picture.eps}%
\caption{An .eps-graphic (probably auto-converted to .pdf via the pstopdf-package)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way:

By default the `filecontents`/`filecontents*`-environment will convert horizontal-tab-characters (code-point number 9 both in ASCII and in Unicode, `^^I` in TeX's `^^`-notation) into spaces. If you don't want this, on many TeX-platforms it suffices to just temporarily set the category code of the horizontal-tab to 12(other) before applying `filecontents`/`filecontents*`.

This could look like this:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^I=12 %
\begin{filecontents*}
[...the content of the filecontents*-environment...]
\end{filecontents*}
\endgroup
```

---

By now I elaborated on `filecontents*` which is an *environment*.
But you did not ask for an environment.
You asked for a *command*.

Some preliminary remarks about TeX before delivering an example of how I might go at implementing a *command*:

TeX takes .tex-input-files for directives for producing tokens. E.g., control-sequence-tokens. E.g., character-tokens. These tokens are appended to the token-stream. This happens in TeX's mouth. The token-stream goes down TeX's gullet. Here expansion of expandable tokens takes place. The results of expansion reach the stomach for further processing.

The crucial point is:

**TeX has subtle rules for creating tokens.**

E.g., whenever TeX starts reading a line of input, some of the first things it does are:

1. Converting the characters from the computer platform's character encoding scheme to the TeX engine's internal character representation scheme which with traditional TeX-engines is ASCII and with LuaTeX/XeTeX-based TeX-engines is Unicode.
2. Removing all space characters at the end of the line. (Space-characters have codepoint-number 32 in the TeX engine's internal character representation scheme.)
3. Appending a character at the end of the line whose code-point-number in the TeX engine's internal character representation scheme corresponds to the value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar`. In case that value is outside the range of code-point-numbers that are possible in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme, no character will be appended.

Item 1 implies that writing to external file requires a routine for converting back to the computer-platform's character encoding scheme. With many TeX platforms this rouine can be configured via so-called TeX-character-translation-files/.tcx-files. **On some TeX platforms/under some circumstances that routine might, e.g., be configured to deliver `^^`-notation for some special characters although your computer-platform can handle these characters. This might lead to copied output differing from what was typed into the .tex-input-file.**

Item 2 implies that TeX will never ever in whatsoever ways process space characters that were written at the end of a line in a .tex-input-file.
**I.e., you can never ever use TeX for copying a sequence of space characters that was written at the end of a line in a .tex-input-file.**

E.g., a character of category code 0(escape)—usually the backslash-character is of that category code—is taken for a signal to not gather a character-token (category code/character code-pair) from a single character but to gather the name of a control sequence token from subsequent characters. (I intend to convey a broad-brushed picture only, so I omit the exact rules for gathering names of control sequence tokens from .tex-input-files here.)

E.g., after creating a control-word-token, the reading-apparatus is set to state S(skipping blanks) which means that subsequent input-characters of category code 10(space) will be ignored/skipped/dropped instead of yielding tokens.

E.g., a character of category code 14(comment) in the .tex-input-file causes TeX to ignore/skip/drop the remaining input-characters of the .tex-input-file's current line instead of forming tokens from them, and to switch the reading-apparatus to state N(new line) and to start reading the next line of the .tex-input-file if present. In state N characters of category code 10(space) found in the .tex-input-file will be ignored/skipped/dropped instead of yielding tokens.

E.g., a character of category code 5(end of line) in the .tex-input-file causes TeX to ignore/skip/drop the remaining characters of the .tex-input-file's current line and to append  depending on the state of the reading-apparatus either (in State N, new line) the token `\par`, or (in State M, middle of line) a space-token, or (in State S, skipping blanks) no token at all to the token-stream, and to switch the reading-apparatus to state N(new line) and to start reading the .tex-input-file's next line if present.

Did you notice the distinction between characters in the .tex-input and character-tokens (with character code and category code) which come into being while the TeX-program is running and which get processed during compilation?

Be that as it may.

All these subtleties related to how TeX at the time of reading the .tex-input-file and creating tokens deals with input-characters depending on category codes and the state of the reading-apparatus lead to the conclusion that, if you wish to process an argument "as is", you need to switch to a category code régime where no characters of the .tex-input will be ignored/skipped/dropped during tokenization, but where each character will yield a (character-)token from which, at the time of writing the tokens to file, that very character will be regained, and where the reading-apparatus during tokenizing a line of .tex-input will always remain in state M (middle of line) and in any case will switch from state N to state M when encountering the very first character of a line of .tex-input, leading to the effect that space-characters at the beginnings of lines of .tex-input will not be ignored. (The above mentioned item 2 implies that even under such a category code régime you cannot prevent the ignoring of space-characters within lines of .tex-input that contain nothing else but space-characters.)

The command `\verb|...|` and the environment `verbatim` (temporarily) switch to a category code régime where this is the case. Henceforth this category code régime is called **"verbatim-catcode-régime"**.

**TeX has subtle rules for writing tokens to external text files.**

E.g., the `\write`-directive will always expand expandable tokens (macros and some primitives), unless they either come from expanding a token-register via `\the` during the `\write`-operation or they come as the *⟨balanced text⟩* of an `\unexpanded`-directive during the `\write`-operation.

E.g., explicit character tokens of category code 6(parameter), i.e., things like hashes (`#`), will be doubled while writing.

E.g., TeX always appends a space-character when unexpanded-writing a control-word-token.

E.g., the `\write`-directve is intended to write a line of text. Therefore the *⟨line-break-characters of your platform⟩* will be appended to the characters which the `\write`-directive forms from its argument for writing.
`\immediate\write\MyNiceFile{\noexpand\LaTeX\relax}`
will deliver
`\LaTeX⟨space character⟩\relax⟨space character⟩⟨line-break-characters of your platform⟩`
Having things in the same line of a text file that come from different `\write`-directives is not possible.

Another interesting question with "using/writing argument as is" is the question how to handle code that in the .tex-input-file is indented.

I fiddled together an approach where xparse's `+v`-argument-type (`+v` denotes that the argument is to be read and tokenized from the .tex-input-file under verbatim-catcode-régime) is used for reading/tokenizing the argument, so that

- linebreaks etc are preserved,
- hashes are not doubled,
- no space-characters (but those at the endings of lines) and the like are lost,
- `^^`-notation in the input will not be converted,

and where writing is done via a token-register whereby unwanted expansion of active characters is suppressed:

With the following example the macro
`\MyWriteFile{⟨text-file's name⟩}{⟨text-file's content⟩}`
(plus all its helper-macros) is defined.

That macro creates anew a text-file of name *⟨text-file's name⟩* and writes *⟨text-file's content⟩* to it.

In the following example that macro is used for creating the text-files `MyFirstBizarreTemp.tex` and `MySecondBizarreTemp.tex`.

The `\verbatiminput*`-command of the [verbatim](https://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim)-package is used for displaying the contents of these text-files.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{verbatim}% <- \verbatiminput* from that package is used for
                     %    displaying the content of text-files 
                     %    that got created during compilation.
                     %    The package is not used otherwise.

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\@firstoftwo{\expandafter}{} \@firstoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo{\expandafter}{} \@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Exchange arguments
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%% Code for  \ReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff
\begingroup
% Dummy-definition, will be overridden. Is used only to get ^^M of 
% category code 12(other) as #1 into subsequent definition-texts:
\NewDocumentCommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{+m}{%
  \endgroup
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Check whether_verbatimized_ argument starts with a endline-character
  %%===========================================================================
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                            {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                              which is to be checked>'s 1st token is a
  %%                              endline-charactern>}%
  %%                            {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                              which is to be checked>'s 1st token is not
  %%                              a endline-character>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl[1]{%
    \UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl\UD@SelDom##1\UD@SelDom#1\UD@@SelDom
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{%
    \long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl##1\UD@SelDom#1##2\UD@@SelDom{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Remove one leading endline-character from _verbatimized_ argument
  %%===========================================================================
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@TrimLeadingEndl{\long\def\UD@@TrimLeadingEndl#1{}}%
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Check whether _verbatimized_ argument ends with a endline-character
  %%===========================================================================
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                               which is to be checked>'s last token is a
  %%                               endline-charactern>}%
  %%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                               which is to be checked>'s last token is not
  %%                               a endline-character>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl[1]{%
    \UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl##1\UD@SelDom#1\UD@SelDom\UD@@SelDom
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl{%
    \long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl##1#1\UD@SelDom##2\UD@@SelDom{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Remove one trailing endline-character from _verbatimized_ argument
  %%===========================================================================
  \newcommand\UD@TrimTrailingEndl[1]{\UD@@TrimTrailingEndl##1\UD@SelDom}%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@TrimTrailingEndl{%
    \long\def\UD@@TrimTrailingEndl##1#1\UD@SelDom{##1}%
  }%
  %%===========================================================================
  %% Remove one leading and one trailing endline-character from _verbatimized_ 
  %% argument if present. Due to \romannumeral0-expansion the result is
  %% delivered in 2 expansion-steps:
  %%===========================================================================
  \newcommand\UD@RemoveLeadingNTrailingEndl[1]{%
    \romannumeral0%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{##1}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl{##1}{%
         \UD@Exchange{ }{%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
         }%
         \expandafter\UD@TrimTrailingEndl\expandafter{\UD@@TrimLeadingEndl##1}%
       }{%
         \UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter}%
         \UD@@TrimLeadingEndl##1%
       }%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingEndl{##1}{%
         \UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
         \UD@TrimTrailingEndl{##1}%
      }{ ##1}%
    }%
  }%
  %%===========================================================================
  %% \ReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff{%
  %%   <Processor-macro><Processor-macro's arguments except Processor-macro's 
  %%   last argument>%
  %% }{<Argument to be read and tokenized under verbatim-catcode-regime>}
  %%
  %% yields:
  %%
  %% <Processor-macro><Processor-macro's arguments except Processor-macro's 
  %% last argument>{<Argument to be read and tokenized under verbatim-
  %%  catcode-regime>}
  %%
  %% I.e., 
  %% \ReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff reads and tokenizes under verbatim-
  %% catcode-régime from the .tex-input-file the last argument for
  %% <Processor-macro> .
  %% 
  %%===========================================================================
  \newcommand*\ReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff[1]{%
    % ##1 = file-name
    \begingroup
    % Make sure horizontal tabs won't cause problems when
    % \ReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff reads its +v-argument:
    \@makeother\^^I%
    \InnerReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff{##1}%
  }%
  \NewDocumentCommand{\InnerReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff}{m+v}{%
    % ##1 = file-name
    % ##2 = argument that got read and tokenized under verbatim-catcode-regime.
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@RemoveLeadingNTrailingEndl{##2}}}{##1}%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Now let's change the catcode of ^^M and then call the dummy-definition
%% of \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl so that it can fetch the catcode-12-^^M,
%% close the group, override itself and define all those macros where that
%% catcode-12-^^M  is needed:
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingEndl{^^M}%
%%End of code for  \ReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

%%=============================================================================
%% Let's define a processor-macro whose first argument is a file-name
%% and whose second argument is the verbatimized-argument:
%%   \MyWriteFileProcessor{<file>}{%
%%      <argument that already got  tokenized under 
%%      verbatim-catcode-regime>%
%%   }
%% writes the <argument that already got  tokenized under verbatim-
%% catcode-regime> to file if the <file> does
%% not exist. If the <file> does exist, you get a message on screen.
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\MyWriteFileProcessor[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \openin\@inputcheck#1\relax
  \ifeof\@inputcheck
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Writing file `\@currdir #1'}%
    \chardef\reserved@c15\relax
    \ch@ck7 \reserved@c\write
    \immediate\openout\reserved@c#1\relax
    \toks@{#2}%
    \begingroup
    % Make sure endline-chars (carriage-return, ^^M in ^^-notation ) 
    % yield linebreaks:
    \newlinechar=`\^^M %
    \immediate\write\reserved@c{\the\toks@}%
    \endgroup
    \immediate\closeout\reserved@c#1\relax
  \else
    \closein\@inputcheck
    \@latex@warning@no@line{%
       File `#1' already exists on the system.\MessageBreak
       Not generating it from this source%
     }
  \fi 
  \endgroup
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Let's define a macro which reads things verbatimized and writes them to file
%% \MyWriteFile{<file-name>}{<Argument to be read and tokenized 
%% under verbatim-catcode-regime and to be written to a new file 
%% with name <file-name> "as is">}
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\MyWriteFile[1]{%
   % #1 = <file-name> ;
   % \ReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff will read and tokenize the
   % <Argument to be read and tokenized under verbatim-catcode-
   % regime> and append the result as another argument to
   % \MyWriteFileProcessor{<file-name>}
   \ReadAndProcessVerbatimizedStuff{\MyWriteFileProcessor{#1}}%
}%
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\enlargethispage{4cm}
\vspace*{-2cm}

\noindent\textbf{The input}

\begin{verbatim*}
  \MyWriteFile{MyFirstBizarreTemp.tex}|
    [This time the content is within verbatim-delimiters.]
    {%
      \Huge
      another
      piece
      of
      text%
      äöü
    }\\
    {\scriptsize another piece of text}
  X|
\end{verbatim*}
  \MyWriteFile{MyFirstBizarreTemp.tex}|
    [This time the content is within verbatim-delimiters.]
    {%
      \Huge
      another
      piece
      of
      text%
      äöü
    }\\
    {\scriptsize another piece of text}
  X|

\noindent\textbf{yields \texttt{MyFirstBizarreTemp.tex} with following content:}

\verbatiminput*{MyFirstBizarreTemp.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null\vspace{\ht\strutbox}

\noindent\textbf{The input}

\begin{verbatim*}
  \MyWriteFile{MySecondBizarreTemp.tex}{
    [This time the content is within curly braces.]
    {%
      \Huge
      another
      piece
      of
      text%
      äöü
    }\\
    {\scriptsize another piece of text}
  X}
\end{verbatim*}
  \MyWriteFile{MySecondBizarreTemp.tex}{
    [This time the content is within curly braces.]
    {%
      \Huge
      another
      piece
      of
      text%
      äöü
    }\\
    {\scriptsize another piece of text}
  X}

\noindent\textbf{yields \texttt{MySecondBizarreTemp.tex} with following content:}

\verbatiminput*{MySecondBizarreTemp.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]